# unmount being invoked when dependency is updated in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have subscribed to some updates from a messaging service in `useEffect` hook. Going through react hooks documentation and resources, I couldn't find answers to some observations with my code. Here is my code snippet:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { messageService } from "../_services";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = messageService.onMessage().subscribe(message => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    });
    return () => {
      console.log("unmount");
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [count]);

  function sendMessage() {
    messageService.sendMessage("message");
  }

  return (
    <div className="jumbotron">
      <button onClick={sendMessage} className="btn btn-primary mr-2">
        Send Message
      </button>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}

export { App };
```

Now I am unable to understand two behaviors:

1. Since `useEffect` hook has `count` as a dependency, I should get an infinite loop issue but I observed is that `unmount` is invoked. Does React unmount the `App` component in anticipation of an infinite loop? I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere if it is doing so
2. even though `unmount` is invoked, the value of `count` is retained. How is it possible

I know one way to solve it is that I need to use `useRef` to retain the `count` and remove it from hook's dependencies along with force update whenever there is count update.

What I am looking for is an answer to the two questions above and if there is a better way of doing this
Thanks in advance.

[Stackblitz link for working app in case you want to try out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-rxjs-communicating-between-components-7avwsw?file=app%2FApp.jsx)

Comment: Just because you `console.log("unmount");` doesn't mean react is *actually* unmounting and remounting the component, it's just an effect cleanup function invoked after each render cycle before the next effect is applied in the next render.

Comment: Why would I unsubscribe and subscribe again and again. Shouldn’t this cleanup or unmount be called only once component is being unmounted. My understanding is it is equivalent to componentDidUnmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanup effect not only clean-up before the component unmounts **but [also](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect)** if a component renders multiple times (**as they typically do**), **the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect**.

Also, in your case, `count` shouldn't be in the `useEffect` as you can use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = messageService.onMessage().subscribe((message) => {
    setCount((p) => p + 1);
  });
  return () => {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

> Even though the unmount is invoked, the value of count is retained. How is it possible?

Thats due to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: Publish in messaging service can be called from any component in the application. I put it here just so that people don’t have to go through all the codebase. So I can’t simply use functional updates. I can update count from subscribe handler only

Comment: What? How is it related? And also focus on the question you asking, if you have something specific you should ask other specific question

Comment: Ohhk got it. i was using the setCount the wrong way. Accepting the answer. Thanks for the help.